# How do I change the visibility of a GUI Frame

Tags: lua, roblox

I am very new at coding and I've tried for a few hours and I cannot change the visibility of a menu ingame that I've added into my game.

This is my code, I am trying to make the frame called "MenuFrame" toggle visibility when the button is clicked.

[The GUI is under "StarterGUI"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXSTG.png)

```
local button = script.Parent
local menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent:FindFirstAncestor("MenuFrame")

local function onButtonClicked()
    if menu.Visible then
        menu.SetAttribute(menu,Visible,false)
    else
        menu.SetAttribute(menu,Visible,true)
    end
end

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(onButtonClicked)
```

The error is `7: attempt to index nil with 'Visible'`

Is there any suggestions on what I could change or fix

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues you are having here, firstly that you are attempting to find the instance by going up the instance tree, then calling FindFirstAncestor. You should instead just directly go to the instance itself, as shown below.

Secondly, Visible is a property of GUIs and not an Attribute. Attributes are solely for developer's use and do not change anything regarding the instances themselves see (https://create.roblox.com/docs/studio/properties#instance-attributes) for more info.
So instead of calling SetAttribute, just index the Visible property and set it

```lua
local button = script.Parent
local menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent

local function onButtonClicked()
    if menu.Visible then
        menu.Visible = false
    else
        menu.Visible = true
    end
end

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(onButtonClicked)
```

Also, to make your code neater, you could instead of the if statement simply use some boolean logic to invert it.

```lua
local function onButtonClicked()
    menu.Visible = not menu.Visible
end
```